# Problems with subscription implementation | deprecated codes

Tags: java, android, android-billing, play-billing-library

let's see if I explain myself correctly, I am trying to implement subscriptions in an application on android studio for the first time, the structure is this:

splash.java -> SubscriptionActivity.java -> MainActivity.java

The user opens the app, shows the splashscreen, then the subscription screen with 5 different plans should appear and after paying the subscription they can access MainActivity.java.

It's my first time doing this and I just see that Google asks that subscriptions be with the new api, I have searched everywhere but I can't do the SubscriptionActivity.java correctly, "is deprecated" appears in several sections and no matter how hard I try To understand the Google guide, I can't update it, I leave you my code and I hope you can please help me.

thank you

**Build.gradle**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'


android {
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.one.two.tree"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 96
        versionName "9.6.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
            apiVersion = '1.1'
            languageVersion = '1.1'
        }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    namespace 'com.one.two.tree'

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.turki-alkhateeb:materialcolorpicker:1.0.7'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')

    // Declare the dependencies for the In-App Messaging and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.0.0'

    dependencies {
        def billing_version = "6.0.1"
        implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"
    }

    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:4.0.0"


    //implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'

}
```

**splash.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentForm;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;


public class splash extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                {

                    startActivity(new Intent(splash.this,SubscriptionActivity.class));
                    finish();

                }

            }
        }, 5000);

    }


}
```

**SubscriptionActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult;
import com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase;
import com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsResponseListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubscriptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BillingClient billingClient;
    private List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList;

    private TextView subscriptionTitleTextView;
    private TextView subscriptionPriceTextView;
    private Button[] subscribeButtons = new Button[5]; // Botones para las 5 suscripciones

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscription);

        subscriptionTitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.subscription_title);
        subscriptionPriceTextView = findViewById(R.id.subscription_price);

        // Encuentra tus botones para las suscripciones
        subscribeButtons[0] = findViewById(R.id.subscribe_button1);
        subscribeButtons[1] = findViewById(R.id.subscribe_button2);
        subscribeButtons[2] = findViewById(R.id.subscribe_button3);
        subscribeButtons[3] = findViewById(R.id.subscribe_button4);
        subscribeButtons[4] = findViewById(R.id.subscribe_button5);

        setupBillingClient();
        querySkuDetails();

        // Configura OnClickListener para los botones de suscripción
        for (int i = 0; i < subscribeButtons.length; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            subscribeButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    initiatePurchase(index);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setupBillingClient() {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
                .build();

        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // El cliente de facturación está listo
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Manejar la desconexión del cliente de facturación
            }
        });
    }

    private void querySkuDetails() {
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add("noads");
        skuList.add("bronze");
        skuList.add("silver");
        skuList.add("gold");
        skuList.add("diamond");

        SkuDetailsParams.Builder paramsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        paramsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList);
        paramsBuilder.setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
        SkuDetailsParams params = paramsBuilder.build();

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> detailsList) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && detailsList != null) {
                    skuDetailsList = detailsList;
                    // Puedes mostrar las opciones de suscripción aquí si es necesario
                    showSubscriptionOptions();
                }
            }
        });
    }




    private void showSubscriptionOptions() {
        for (int i = 0; i < subscribeButtons.length; i++) {
            if (skuDetailsList.size() > i) {
                subscribeButtons[i].setText(skuDetailsList.get(i).getTitle() + " - " + skuDetailsList.get(i).getPrice());
                subscribeButtons[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                subscribeButtons[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void initiatePurchase(int index) {
        if (skuDetailsList != null && index < skuDetailsList.size()) {
            BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(index))
                    .build();
            billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, flowParams);
        }
    }

    private final PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
            // Lógica para manejar la respuesta de la compra
        }
    };
}
```

**activity_subscription.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SubscriptionActivity">

    <!-- Imagen en la parte superior -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/icono"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <!-- Texto debajo de la imagen -->

    <!-- Precio de la suscripción -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Subscription Title"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewTop"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subscription Price"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

    <!-- Botones para las suscripciones -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subscribe_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subscribe 1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscription_price"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subscribe_button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subscribe 2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscribe_button1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subscribe_button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subscribe 3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscribe_button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subscribe_button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subscribe 4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscribe_button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subscribe_button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subscribe 5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subscribe_button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in SubscriptionActivity.java it tells me "is deprecated" and I don't know how to fix it, not even by reading the documentation.

The error says it in:

1. private List skuDetailsList;
2. SkuDetailsParams.Builder paramsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
3. SkuDetailsParams params = paramsBuilder.build();
4. billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener()
5. .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(index))

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a warning and an exception? Does your code actually work in spite of the deprecation warnings?

Comment: @MarsAtomic The buttons do nothing, I have tried uploading an internal test version to Google Play and when I press the buttons it does not show me any subscription, as I understood, Google requires that everything be updated when subscriptions are added for the first time.